# Calling an ASP.NET page from a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, forms

I have a static page that contains a form.

```
<form METHOD="post" ACTION="...">           
  <input type="submit" value="Verzenden"  />        
</form>
```

When the submit button is clicked, I want the form fields to be sent to an ASP.NET page, in which I receive the form fields and do something with them (like sending a mail).

I was thinking to do something like this:

```
<form METHOD="post" ACTION="http://localhost:3384/mail.aspx">           
  <input type="submit" value="Verzenden"  />        
</form>
```

But how can I receive this data in the mail.aspx code behind?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="Default.aspx" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fullname">
<select name="color">
    <option value="Red">Red $10.00</option>
    <option value="Blue">Blue $8.00</option>
    <option value="Green">Green $12.00</option>
</select>
<select name="size">
    <option value="Small">Small</option>
    <option value="Large">Large</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Verzenden" />
</form>
```

[image]

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FullNameLabel.Text = Request.Form["fullname"];
    ColorLabel.Text = Request.Form["color"];
    SizeLabel.Text = Request.Form["size"];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now I see the reason it's not working: I specified an id for the input type, but not name! It seems that name is needed to be able to get the data in the Request! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Request.Form` collection:

```
string verz = Request.Form["Verzenden"];
etc...
```

Doing this in `Page_Load` is easiest. It's probably best to avoid having a typical postback form on that page, just to keep things simple; otherwise, you have to test for `IsPostBack` to make sure you should read the `Form` values.

Comment: If I use POST in the form, Page_Load is not called. If I use GET, Page_Load is called but RequestForm is empty. So it seems not to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

or from the queryString
`Request.queryString["fieldname"];`

Comment: The form's "method" needs to be "GET" in order to retrieve the values from the Request.QueryString collection.

Comment: Yes, but can I use POST and Form instead of GET and querystring?